# PowerShell script parameters not parsed correctly

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a simple script which does not work:

```
Param([string] $Input, [string] $Output)
Write-Host $Input
Write-Host $Output
```

The `$Input` parameter does not get printed:

```
PS> .\Get-Parameters.ps1 "First" "Second"

Second
```

If I rename `$Input` to `$Joe` the script works fine. `$Input` is not a reserved name.

What is going on? I am perplexed.

Comment: Did you read `help about_Automatic_Variables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell's `$input` is an automatic variable:

basically `$input` in an enumerator which provides access to the actual pipeline.

Reading about [`$input`](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/)

Comment: See [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) and [Automatic Variables](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html)

Comment: @emddudley The second link tell `$Input` is case-sensitive... really isn't it!!

Answer (score 1):

$input in an enumerator which provides access to the pipeline you have.

reference here:  [$Input Gotchas](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/)